# Strange behavior of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have this model class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Collection1 { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public virtual ICollection<User> Collection2 { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

Then I add a few records in the database:

```
var context = new UsersContext();

var user1 = new User();
var user2 = new User();
var user3 = new User();

user1.Name = "user1";
user2.Name = "user2";
user3.Name = "user3";

user1.Collection1.Add(user2);
user2.Collection1.Add(user3);

context.Users.Add(user1);
context.Users.Add(user2);
context.Users.Add(user3);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Then I run this query:

```
var user2 = context.Users.First(user => user.Name == "user2");

foreach (var u in user2.Collection2)
    Console.WriteLine($"{user2.Name}  Collection2 {u.Name}");
```

And I get:

> user2 Collection2 user1

Why in `Collection2` do I have a record? And how to fix it ?

**UPDATE.**

[image]

This is a link to the test project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxP-1gZwSGL5S1c4cWN1Q2NsYVU/view

Comment: Question not clear. Do you mean why there's a record or why the record is 'user1'?

Comment: Actually interesting behavior. Looks like EF has setup `many-to-many` relationship for you. You can verify that by looking at the generated tables.

Comment: @peval27, Sorry for my English. Why in collection2 have a record? 
I did not add it.

Comment: @Lightness I believe declaring it as virtual collection means implicitly linking to a table of users called Collection2. Check the tables created in the DB

Comment: Please look at my project. You will see what the problem is. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxP-1gZwSGL5S1c4cWN1Q2NsYVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Choose to live a happy life and do not let EF generate the database for you. Do it with SQL

Comment: @IvanStoev,  Please look at my project. I added link to question.

Comment: @Lightness It might be that Entity is creating a many-to-many relationship. Indeed it creates a UsersUsers table with a mapping. What are you trying to achieve? why class User has two collections of users, what's the purpose?

Comment: @peval27, I am making a messenger application and I need to store information about contacts and invitations and those are also user entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not strange, but expected behavior.

Consider the following model:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entity2> Collection2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entity1> Collection1 { get; set; }
}
```

This is a typical EF `many-to-many` relationship with implicit junction table. When you add `entity1` to `entity2.Collection1`, it also adds `entity2` to `entity1.Collection2`.

Now substitute `Entity1 = Entity2 = User`. The result is exactly your model.

Shortly, with that model EF creates self `many-to-many` relationship via implicit `UsersUsers` junction table, that's why you get the described behavior.

Since your intention seems to be having two `one-to-many` relations, you need to tell that explicitly to EF by using Fluent API:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.Collection1).WithOptional();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.Collection2).WithOptional();
    }
}
```

Now everything will work as expected.